# Prevent class remove on hash change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have jquery assigning active class to my main and contextual navigation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location;
            $('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
                return this.href == url;
            }).parent().addClass('active-dropdown').parent().parent().addClass('active');
            var url = window.location;
            $('ul.contextual-navigation a').filter(function () {
                return this.href == url;
            }).parent().addClass('contextual-active');
            $('<i class="icon-hand-right"></i>').prependTo('.contextual-active'); 
        });

    </script>
```

For example, when url is /about/index.html class is assigned as expected, but when it changes to /about/index.html#team active class is being removed. Is there a way to keep active class assigned to main and contextual navigation when #hashtag is active within that page.

Answer (score 0):

Not use window.location.href here, use window.location.pathname instead.
You can see
[Link anatomy](http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589)

to know more about window.location